# How to find hidden files in webIDE of SAP Cloud Platform?

Tags: sap-cloud-platform

My sapUI5 project in SAP WebIDE can not run, and the error msg in console is :

> The project  is corrupted because its '.user.project.json' file has an invalid JSON format.Open the file and fix it.

But there is only `project.json` in my project. I tried to new a '.user.project.json' file, but the `OK` button turned disabled. I think this file is already existed in my project, but where to find it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SAP WebIDE, that file is hidden by default. To see it, you have to press the "Show Hidden Files" button.

[image: WebIDE Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks very much!! It turns out that git conflict has changed the file.

Comment: I am going to add it to .gitignore!